# extract a webtest response in Visual Studio 2012 using C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

**PROBLEM SOLVED**

I have a coded webtest file running in Visual Studio 2012.
In one of those web requests, when I click on the Response tab, there are Headers and Body.

My question is how do I extract information from the Body in C# ? I need to use the information in the next WebTestRequest

EDIT:
I tried this method just now:

```
        string test = "";
        request23.ExtractValues += (d, e) =>
        {
            WebTestResponse haha = e.Response;
            test = haha.BodyString.ToString();

            test = Regex.Replace(test, @"\D", ""); //remove any non-digits coz I need the ID
        };
```

It works, I got the value I wanted. But then I run it again and it only returns empty string. [EDIT]: Restarted Visual Studio and it works again

Comment: Check HtmlAgilityPack if you want to check anything inside the html body

Comment: its not a HTML body. it is a response like this:
0x00000000  7B  22  6E  61  6D  65  22  3A  22  41  74  74  61  63  68  6D    {"name":"Attachm
0x00000010  65  6E  74  22  2C  22  69  64  22  3A  22  36  32  33  32  32    ent","id":"62322
0x00000020  34  35  39  39  39  32  38  33  31  34  35  31  34  31  22  7D    45999283145141"}

Sorry I cant post images to make you see it clearer

Comment: What type of application you are testing Asp.net webform, Asp.net MVC?
I think your response is in JSON

Comment: Yes this is what contained in the headers :

HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
X-AREQUESTID : 1091x496283x1
X-ASESSIONID : t04yo0
Pragma : no-cache
X-Seraph-LoginReason : OK
X-AUSERNAME : aabduls
X-Content-Type-Options : nosniff
Transfer-Encoding : chunked
Connection : close
Cache-Control : no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
Content-Type : application/json;charset=UTF-8
Date : Fri, 11 Oct 2013 10:11:53 GMT
Expires : Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
Server : Apache-Coyote/1.1